# Bravely Default - Summoner Class

Tags: bravely-default

So, I'm just being curious here: how fast does one get the summoner class in Bravely Default? I could look it up, but I don't want to get SPOILED ( so please, no SPOILERS ).
For reference, I just finished ... let's call it Clocksville and am now on a ... fashion quest.

Thanks for the input

Comment: Generally it is expected/required that you perform *some* research on your own before asking a question here.  Refusing to do so in order to avoid spoilers isn't really a valid reason to lazily ask instead.  That's likely the reason for the downvotes on the question.

Comment: I knew everything I needed to know about what the class does (yay research), but I didn't want to get spoiled story wise as to when I was getting it. Call it lazy if you will, I call it 'wanting to enjoy the story'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the summoner class in Chapter 2.

> It is about two or three boss fights in.

The Summoner class is not all it's cracked up to be unfortunately. You have to collect the summons and at the time you get the class you only have access to two summons.

How to get summons:

> You have to talk to the Owl looking guys that you may have noticed. You just have to talk to them and survive one hit from the summon and then you will earn the right to cast it. They aren't particularly strong unfortunately.

Comment: Summoners are great for farming Exp, JP or Money. Pairing it with a  secondary SwordMaster with Free Lunch gives you a first turn sweep of most mobs if you brave 4 times. Free Lunch + Summon * 3 kills most mobs even late game and you dont lose a single point of MP. Rinse Repeat.